# Does one ever need infinitely many cohomologies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, string-theory, mathematical-physics, gauge-theory

In a theory containing gauge fields or higher-form gauge fields, if the background spacetime is a complicated manifold, a nice way to represent the configuration of the gauge field mathematically is with a vector bundle. Often, important aspects of the configuration are captured in the cohomologies of the vector bundle, which are a small set of integers. (One context in which this is particularly true is compactification, where these integers typically count the massless fields seen in the uncompactified dimensions.)

Vector bundle cohomologies are usually very difficult to compute. In particular, this makes it impossible to obtain information for any significant set of vector bundles.

My question is whether this limitation prevents any particular calculations:

**Q: Are there any contexts in physics where a calculation requires the computation of the cohomologies of a very large or even infinite number of vector bundles?**

An example might be a partition function that requires a sum over cohomology values.

Comment: The singular cohomology of a manifold vanishes in every degree higher than the dimension of the manifold. Hence for these cohomology theories the answer is negative or at least it forms no problem.

Comment: @NDewolf Sorry, I haven't made myself clear. What I am asking about is whether one needs to know the cohomologies of an infinite number of vector bundles. I will edit the question - thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: By cohomologies of a vector bundle, are you talking about its characteristic classes?

Comment: @pianyon Cohomologies are abelian groups associated to the bundle. The simplest example is the zeroth cohomology, which is the group of sections of the bundle.

Comment: So instead of singular cohomology and alternatives it seems you are interested in sheaf (hyper)cohomology?

Comment: @NDewolf Yes, the bundle cohomologies are equal to the sheaf cohomologies if the bundle is viewed as a sheaf. Alternatively, bundle cohomologies are given by the de Rham cohomologies of differential forms valued in the bundle.

Comment: Wait, is this true? I thought that de Rham was isomorphic to Cech cohomology (or equivalently sheaf cohomology) of the constant $\mathbb{R}$-sheaf and not the structure sheaf, the latter giving rise to global sections through its zeroth cohomology group.

Comment: @NDewolf By 'the bundle' I meant whichever vector bundle one is considering, not some bundle canonically associated to the manifold. In particular, for any given bundle, one can consider differential forms which have an additional transformation rule between patches given by the bundle transition functions.These forms can be closed or exact, so that one can define cohomology groups. Maybe it is not correct to call this an instance of de Rham cohomology.

Comment: No I understand, but even then. The cohomology of the vector bundle, which i interpret as meaning the singular cohomology of the bundle as a manifold itself, is not the same as the sheaf cohomology. E.g. for connected bundles one has $H^0=\mathbb{R}$ and it should be clear that the global sections of a (connected) vector bundle are definitely not always isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 4):

I will try to say something about the string theory part of the answer.

Here there are some examples where an infinite number vector bundles/sheaves are important:

**1) Holography:** All known examples of quantum field theories with gravity duals have large $N$ limits. For large $N$ dualities to work, a gigantic number $N$ of color charges are needed. In the physical AdS/CFT correspondence that translates into the fact that there are allowed interactions in between an infinite number of "color bundles"(talking about the CFT side).

See Yin's talk on the computation of $1/16$ BPS states in $N=4$ SYM for an interesting example of a situation where an actual computation of an infinite number of representatives of Lie algebra cohomology classes is important [Xi Yin - Comments on BPS states in N=4 SYM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbyPI1MFbGA).

**2)** In **topological strings and topological field theories** the situation is rather similar. Large $N$ dualities in those contexts requiere an infinite amount of (quasi-coherent but not coherent) sheaves supported over a homology class. Then, to exactly compute the spectrum of open strings or gluons (and their interactions) we need to take into account an infinite number of sheaf cohomology classes at the same time. See [On the Gauge Theory/Geometry Correspondence](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/25249582.pdf).

**3) Quiver gauge theories:** The possible fractional branes in a quiver are identified with the derived bounded category of quiver representations (or coherent sheaves in the associated quiver variety); see [Topological branes from descent](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.0168) for a proof of the fact that any object in the derived category is a boundary condition for the B-model. The fact that every complex is bounded (all their nodes are zero, except for a finite number of them) does not rule out the possibility that an infinite number of complexes of sheaves could be relevant in some computation. See [crystal melting and black holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0610005) for an interesting example.

**4) Topological gravity:** All the amplitudes in Kodaira-Spencer theory of gravity can be computed enforcing an infinite number of conditions coming from the symmetries of an infinite dimensional algebra. See [Topological Strings and Integrable Hierarchies](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0312085) and [Supersymmetric Gauge Theories, Intersecting Branes and Free Fermions](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.4446).